# IOS : how can i make provisioning profile and how to add UDID number in account and is it posssible to have multiple UDID with one account?

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I am new in iphone development.
What is development provisioning profile?
// this type of thing is not required in android.

And also explain me a when i execute a ionic run ios , what things i have to be in mind.

Please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: bro read from here https://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood  .  try to learn basics from raywenderlich which a awesome tutorial site.

Comment: learn from this link and create your development provisioning profile http://docs.twixlmedia.com/m/twixl-publisher-app/l/243373-creating-provisioning-profiles-for-ios-apps

Comment: Apple also provide a free to test your application. See this link.. its a very help full

https://livecode.com/how-to-create-a-free-ios-development-provisioning-profile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an [apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com) and link your xcode ide to your account. Because you can't build or run an ios application without signing it with your profile.

Comment: Apple also provide a free to test your application.
See this link.. its a very help full
https://livecode.com/how-to-create-a-free-ios-development-provisioning-profile/